# mysqli_real_escape_string not work?

Tags: php, mysql

Can somebody know why mysqli doen't work in some servers?

```
$mysqli = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
echo '-'.mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,"ab'c").'-';
mysqli_close($mysqli);
```

It display "--" insted of "-ab\'c-"

Comment: Please check your mysqli_connect constants are correct or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is only 1 possible explanation of this. Your connection failed to get established and `$mysqli` is not a valid MySQLi Resource.

```
var_dump($mysqli);
```

That will confirm this.